# Irregularity with $3k$ / $3k +1$ representation of perfect square integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I noticed:
$111$ can be represented as $3k$ for $k = 37$
and similarly $1111$ can be represented as $3k+1$ for $k=370$
but $111$ and $1111$ are not perfect square, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you think that every such number is a perfect square ? It is the other way round : Every perfect square has one of the given forms.

Comment: that's fair, thanks for answering this silly question

Comment: $7$ is of the form $3k+1,$ but is not a perfect square. It is a perfect square, modulo $3,$ since $2^2\equiv 7\pmod 3.$